# What this means? "I am focused only on the essentials, to the exclusion of all else."

Tags: grammar

"I am focused only on the essentials, to the **exclusion** of all else."

This is a line from movie Ad Astra.

I am not quite sure what does the rear part of the sentence mean. Does this mean I am focus on the something, and therefor ignore others?

Can I rewrite it this way?

I am focused only on the essentials.
I am focused to the exclusion of all else.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Repeating 'I am focused' doesn't make sense. You could instead say 'I am not focused on anything else'.

Comment: or "I am focused on nothing else"